# Alphabetizing an index

Tags: word-order

What is the proper way to alphabetize acronyms in an index. The particular words in question are: "U.S. Constitutional Law" and "urbanization." Which should be listed first?

Comment: Why don't you try looking up "urbanization" and "U.S." in a (paper) dictionary and see which they list first? I'd recommend the OED if you can get your hands on the copy.

Comment: Related: *[Alphabetizing List of Mixed Words and Acronyms](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103348)*. Pedants will also note that *U.S.* is not an acronym but an initialism, a different kind of abbreviation.

Comment: Acronyms should appear in the index, with their spelled-out name in parentheses; and the spelled-out name should **also** appear alphabetized in the index, with its acronym in parentheses. Redundancy is your friend in indexing.

Comment: I would consider including entries for "Constitutional law, U.S." and for "law, U.S. Constitutional" as well as for "U.S. Constitutional law" (which I would place after the entry for "urbanization"). Because "U.S." is so widely accepted as a short form for "United States" (used as an adjective) in formal writing—and because "United States" and "U.S." tend to appear in close proximity to one another in most indexes—I would not also include an entry for "United States Constitutional law." Even so, I think John Lawler's point about redundancy in index entries is generally very sound.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the question of whether you should include various redundant entries for "U.S. Constitutional law"—such as "Constitutional law, U.S.," "law, U.S. Constitutional," and "United States Constitutional law"—in your index, style guides do attempt to answer your question about how to alphabetize initialisms and acronyms. Unfortunately, their answers do not entirely agree with one another. First, from *Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003):

> **18.62** *Abbreviations.* Acronyms, initialisms, and most abbreviations are alphabetized as they appear, not according to their spelled out versions, and are interspersed alphabetically among entries. [Cross references omitted.]
>
> [Relevant example:]
>
> > NATO
> >
> > North Pole
> >
> > NOW (National Organization for Women)

*Words Into Type*, third edition (1974), takes a somewhat more nuanced approach to the question, noting that it is common in indexes for the abbreviations *St.* (for *Saint*), *Ft.* (for *Fort*), an *Mt.* (for *Mount*) to be "alphabetized as they are to be read" (that is, alphabetized as though they were spelled out in full). But having acknowledged these exceptions, *Words Into Type* continues:

> All other abbreviations fall into this second category and are alphabetized letter by letter, as they appear to the eye. For example, *RNA* [the initialism for *ribonucleic acid*] should come after *rm* and before *ro* and should be cross-referenced to the spelled out term as follows:
>
> > RNA. *See* Ribonucleic acid (RNA).

The *Oxford Guide to Style* (2002) takes yet another tack, asserting that indexer may follow either a word-by-word system or a letter-by-letter system. The difference is not trivial where acronyms and initialisms are concerned:

> In both systems, letter groups are treated as one word if—like 'NATO' and 'NASA'—they are pronounced as such [in other words, if they are acronyms rather than initialisms]. Otherwise, the word-by-word system lists all set of letters before any full word, ignoring any full points:
>
> > *Word-by-word*[:] I/O, IOU, IPA, i.p.i., IPM, i.p.s., IP address, Ipanema, iodine, Iowa
> >
> > *Letter-by-letter*[:] I/O, iodine, IOU, Iowa, IPA, IP address, Ipanema, i.p.i., IPM, i.p.s.

Oxford's presentation of the letter-by-letter set of entries matches the order you would expect from the discussions in *Chicago* and in *Words Into Type*. In contrast, I find its presentation of the word-by-word set of entries somewhat baffling—specifically, in connection with its placement of "IP address," which I would have expected to fall immediately after "IPA" but which instead (owing to the force of the complete word "address" after "IP") follows "i.p.s."

A rationale for its handling of "IP address"—a term that combines an initialism and a plain word—would have been helpful, as would an indication of how to handle mixed terms in which the initialism comes second. For example, would "high IQ" appear before or after "high anxiety" in an index based on Oxford's word-for-word system? And would "high ID standards" appear before or after "high IQ"?

Another complication is that, given Oxford's rather opaque explanation of how the system works, I don't know whether "ISIS" would appear between "i.p.i.s." and "IP address" in the word-for-word list (because it is sometimes pronounced as an initialism, "I-S-I-S") or after "Iowa" (because, like "NATO" and "NASA" it is often pronounced acronymically, as "Isis").

In view of the vagaries (or vagueries) of Oxford's word-by-word system, I would be strongly inclined to follow the letter-by-letter system if I had the choice, not only because it is simpler to construct from an indexer's point of view, but because it yields a more intuitively arranged index from a reader's perspective. In a letter-by-letter system, clearly, the entry for "U.S. Constitutional law" would follow—not precede—the entry for "urbanization."

Answer (score -3):

U.S. (A) stands for United States (of America). For anyone born here or, more importantly, who "served" here (in the U.S.{A}) they would mean the same thing. In other words, U.S.(A.) IS United States (of America), therefore, it would lead "urbanization."

Comment: In which alphabet would _United_ follow _urbanization_?

Comment: This is a very confusing answer. Are you saying *us-* follows *ur-* or *un-* follows *ur-*?